# Why is my WebBrowser component using IE proxy settings despite changing the DefaultWebProxy?

Tags: .net, proxy, browser

In the program I am maintaining, the user can set their own proxy settings, in which case the DefaultWebProxy is set to a new proxy with those settings, in the case that they don't DefaultWebProxy is set to null.

However, if I set duff proxy settings in internet explorer, the WebBrowser stops working, sending any navigation requests to res://ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff_webOC.htm#http://www.google.co.uk, and if i clear the IE settings, it works again.

Does the WebBrowser ignore the DefaultWebProxy and go straight to IE or is something else to blame?